# Cross-compilation: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm having a rather weird problem using an lm32 cross-compiler. I have installed the same software on multiple different machines (real ones and VMs) and OS (SL6, SL7, CentOS 6, CentOS 7). I am at a point that I have a SL7 VM and a real machine running SL7. They are using the same yum packets and self-compiled programs, also the environment is the same. However, on the latter machine I get this error:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory 
lm32-elf-gcc    -c -o arch/lm32/crt0.o arch/lm32/crt0.S
lm32-elf-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I can't really figure out why it can't find its own cc1 tool. Can someone hint me into the right direction who had a similar problem?

Comment: Looks like "*the latter machine*"'s gcc installation is broken.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really see why. The lm32 install is precompiled and works in the VM and the gcc that I compiled myself is definitely working (I also tried with the OS one, same result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to be the file system... xfs is using 64 bit inodes on the real machines and the lm32 gcc does not cope. Look here for further information: http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/sw/inodes64.html
Using an ext4 file system fixed it for me (i.e. a different partition formatted using ext4) and using the gcc and the code to compile from there